# Get filename when using urllib.urlopen

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

I'm using `urllib.urlopen` to read a file from a URL. What is the best way to get the filename? Do servers always return the `Content-Disposition` header?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally, you provide the "filename" when you make a URI request.  What are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an optional header, so no. See if it exists, and if not then fall back to checking the URL.